# How do I View Error Messages in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

I am trying to associate a file extension (.ipynb) with vscodein midnight commander.

I edited my "file extensions" file.

When I try and launch the file, the screen flashes black and then goes back to normal, launching nothing.

When i enter "%p% in the command bar, I see a sort of console with error messages, but it disappears before I can read it.

How can I read the error message I'm getting from my attempt to launch the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pressing Ctrl+O will switch to the output window, where you can read the error messages. Pressing Ctrl+O again will switch back to the normal MC screen.